# Spark:- What could be the idle parameters to process 300 GB data in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

To process 300 GB data, Could you please provide me the following figures.

> Job reads the data , make the data frame , apply some filters and aggregates and write the data

I have good cluster with 640 GM RAM and 160 cores. (10 nodes with 64 GB RAM and each node contains 16 cores)

1. Idle executor memory (in case not using any cache)(without any spill)
2. Idle executor memory (in case using cache)
3. Idle driver memory (not doing any collect)
4. Idle cores (cores for parallelism, let me know each core handle how much data)
5. Best partition block data size (I think default 64 MB but what is the best 128 MB or 256 MB)
6. No of shuffle partitions (default 200)

**Note:** Always think about processing the large data perspective and optimize solution

Comment: The most important part of the question thats missing: what do u want to do with this 300GB data? do u just want to read and write them? Or run some SQL statements on top of it?

Comment: Generally there are no thumb rules to tell what nubers work well. you need to start with 1core executors and 1GB executor memory and keep increasing them and see where the job hotspots/ performs well. this is iterative process

Comment: @chen I have added job details :- Job reads the data , make the data frame , apply some filters and aggregates and write the data

Comment: like @chen suggested, there aren't any rules here that work for all. you'd have to do trials with your data & purpose to reach an optimum point.

Comment: Can you clear one thing , **suppose executor memory is 15 GB RAM and using 5 cores**. `then each core reads 3 gb data parallelly then again it divides into small 128MB data block`. Am i understanding correct?